# deviceorientation of javascript event is not firing in chrome android

Tags: javascript, three.js, device-orientation

1. I am trying to fire deviceorientation event of javascript but event is not firing in my android device.    [please check out event documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent)
   [image: This is what i have tried in chrome desktop sensors which works fine]

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
  console.log(event.alpha + ' : ' + event.beta + ' : ' + event.gamma);
});
```

2. It works fine in chrome desktop and event is getting triggered.
   (Google chrome -> Inspect -> customize and control devTools ->more Tools -> sensors -> orientation (turn it on and rotate virtual device).

3.But if i open this link from any android device event is not working . I am not able to see any console log or alert..Is there any extra settings required to get orientation details from android..

any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` exists to see if it's supported? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/device-orientation/

Comment: ya it is supported for chrome and android web version..u can check in the link i have given ...and check with browser compatibility

Answer (score 21):

You need to open page with https:// even if you don't have installed any SSL cert.

Comment: Why should this be a solution?

Comment: because of this https://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/#security-and-privacy. But it works in my Chrome desktop without https too.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working in https either now.  Even three.js example page isn't working for me... https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html

Comment: Amazing! This totally worked out for me (and I waas really getting frustrated here!). Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Restrictions of Chromium's "powerful features" to secure origins are described (along with their workarounds) [here](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins/).

Comment: Still doesn't work for me even the example on MDN doesn't work https://live-samples.mdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_orientation_events/Detecting_device_orientation/_sample_.Orientation_example.html

Answer (score 3):

Currently, I am facing same problem. In Chrome desktop `deviceorientation` events seems to be working, but on Chrome Android they are not. Additionally in FireFox the things are vice versa.

I don't know why. But I can suggest a very basic thing to try and another one as a solution to make it work on Chrome, also on FireFox, both desktop and Android.

First one just uninstall your Chrome browser, or only the updates to it, then reinstall it. It has fixed the `deviceorientation` problem on my phone.

The other one is as follows:

You can use one of [OrientationSensor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OrientationSensor)s, namely `AbsoluteOrientationSensor` and `RelativeOrientationSensor`, of [Sensor APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/API/Sensor_APIs) to make things work on Chrome Android and still keep `deviceorientation` way as a fallback for where it works, ie. Chrome desktop and FireFox Android. Sensor APIs available in only Chrome as I see. These `Sensor APIs` needs in secure contexts, like **https** pages and more (https://www.w3.org/TR/secure-contexts/). I want to add more about the absoluteness of a devices orientation measurement in web: As the names of these two sensor apis suggest one is for absolute orientation ie. relative to the true North of the Earth, the other is relative. You can achieve the absoluteness with `deviceorientation` event too if you get its `absolute` property `true` from your browser. It will be `false` if your device do not have a *magnetometer* theoretically. Also, mobile Safari does not care about this last property. Yikes! It has another property `webkitCompassHeading`, which you can see it mentioned in [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/deviceorientationevent) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent) but not in the spec itself. Again, in the `deviceorientation` event spec there are mentionings of two different things not mentioned in Apple Developer or MDN [`compassneedscalibration` Event](https://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/#compassneedscalibration) and [`deviceorientationabsolute` Event](https://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/#deviceorientationabsolute). But I do not see any of them in my `deviceorientation` event in my browsers. Seems like no body cares.

As a personal additional remark, I think this should not be so complicated. Just give us `absolute` props value as `true` or `false` then the `alpha` is constantly related to the compass angle from true or magnetic North, whatever. [`Sensor APIs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/API/Sensor_APIs) is coming to solve these but not yet implemented much.

Combined with Permissions API, you must use as follows (from MDN example) :

```
const sensor = new AbsoluteOrientationSensor();
Promise.all([navigator.permissions.query({ name: "accelerometer" }),
             navigator.permissions.query({ name: "magnetometer" }),
             navigator.permissions.query({ name: "gyroscope" })])
       .then(results => {
         if (results.every(result => result.state === "granted")) {
           sensor.start();
           ...
         } else {
           console.log("No permissions to use AbsoluteOrientationSensor.");
         }
   });
```

This API gives you a quaternion which very useful object for orientations and rotations and very handy if you are especially working with three.js or babylonjs or similar. Use the sensor's `onreading` event handler or `reading` event to get the quaternion and use it to update your *scene camera* or other object's orientation in *render loop* of your 3d engine of choice.

Some examples you can check code from developer tools inspector (down the page is an AbsoluteOrientationSensor example):

https://sensorbox.glitch.me

One of the comments above suggests that you **must** use https in order to make the `deviceorientation` events work. That is true by specification as I understand from here: https://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/#security-and-privacy, but it works on **http** pages as far as I have tried. And in your case, same as mine, it will not work regardless it is in an **https** page.

Hope it helps, it is kind of mess in here in current state of the art in web development with sensors.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. On my iOS device both orientation methods gets stuck on loading on your example page: https://sensorbox.glitch.me

is there a setting I need to fix or is this outdated?