# Capacitor Motion plugin not showing as installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I've been trying to add Motion capabilities to my Capacitor app and, despite installing like all other plugins that do work, the Motion plugin does not appear in my plugins list or in the `Capacitor.Plugins` object in JavaScript.

Like all other plugins, I installed using `npm install @capacitor/motion` and then synced with `npx cap sync`. The installation appears successful, but then listing plugins via `npx cap ls` shows all plugins *except* Motion.

Installation results:

```
% npm install @capacitor/motion

added 1 package, and audited 16 packages in 860ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I then did an `npx cap sync` and copied the updated `capacitor.js` to my server location.

Plugin list results:

```
% cap ls

[info] Found 10 Capacitor plugins for android:
       @capacitor-community/screen-brightness@1.0.1
       @capacitor/browser@1.0.0
       @capacitor/dialog@1.0.0
       @capacitor/geolocation@1.0.0
       @capacitor/haptics@1.0.0
       @capacitor/local-notifications@1.0.0
       @capacitor/screen-reader@1.0.0
       @capacitor/status-bar@1.0.0
       @capacitor/text-zoom@1.0.0
       @capacitor/toast@1.0.0
[info] Found 10 Capacitor plugins for ios:
       @capacitor-community/screen-brightness@1.0.1
       @capacitor/browser@1.0.0
       @capacitor/dialog@1.0.0
       @capacitor/geolocation@1.0.0
       @capacitor/haptics@1.0.0
       @capacitor/local-notifications@1.0.0
       @capacitor/screen-reader@1.0.0
       @capacitor/status-bar@1.0.0
       @capacitor/text-zoom@1.0.0
       @capacitor/toast@1.0.0
[info] Listing plugins for web is not possible.
```

Contents of `Capacitor.Plugins` object in JavaScript:

```
Capacitor.Plugins: {
  Browser,
  Dialog,
  Geolocation,
  Haptics,
  LocalNotifications,
  ScreenBrightness,
  ScreenReader,
  StatusBar,
  TextZoom,
  Toast,
  WebView
}
```

Is there some other way I should be accessing `Capacitor.Plugins.Motion` to listen for `orientation` events?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Correction/Update:** Per @jcesarmobile's comment below, the Motion API is *not* deprecated, I just likely can't use it because my content is hosted on a LAN server without https, which the JavaScript motion API requires.

~ ~ ~ ~

The Motion plugin has been deprecated: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1499

Instead, we must use `deviceorientation` and `devicemotion` events on `window`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicemotion_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/deviceorientation_event

A heads up to anyone who's looking to use those events on localhost or a standard http server, they are only available via https.

See this question: [deviceorientation of javascript event is not firing in chrome android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57934416/deviceorientation-of-javascript-event-is-not-firing-in-chrome-android)

Comment: Motion plugin is not deprecated, it doesn't appear listed because it's a web only plugin, even in the native platforms it uses the web implementation. Web only plugins are not added to the Plugins object, so you can only use it if you import the plugin from its package.

Comment: @jcesarmobile - Thanks for the clarification! So I wouldn't be able to use it with vanilla JavaScript, then? Even if I use a packager, is there any way I can use it without needing to host on a secure server?

Comment: Yeah, if you use a packager you can use it with vanilla JavaScript. On iOS and Android should work without a secure context because iOS considers the local assets secure and Android loads from `http://localhost`, which is an exception (or you can also configure the app to use `https://localhost`

Comment: Our setup requires that we host our web apps on the local network rather than on device or in the cloud on a server with SSL. All plugins so far have worked great with this setup, but the https requirement of the motion APIs means we can't host them on our LAN server. We may just need to figure out a hybrid solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Capacitor is for distributing your assets in your app. If you are loading from an url in your local network it won’t work unless you do port forwarding (which will require to configure all your devices and I don’t think it’s possible on iOS). You can probably use something like ngrok, it’s what I use for testing web APIs that require https without configuring certificates